# Linq data mapping: usage of Storage property on column attribute

Tags: c#, linq, mapping

Can somebody please explain the difference between the following 3 possibilities for using the `ColumnAttribute`:

A: attribute on field

```
[Column(Name="ParentId")]
private int m_parentid;
public int ParentId { get { return m_parentid; } set { m_parentid = value; } }
```

B: attribute on property

```
private int m_parentid;
[Column(Name="ParentId")]
public int ParentId { get { return m_parentid; } set { m_parentid = value; } }
```

C: attribute on property with storage set

```
private int m_parentid;
[Column(Name="ParentId", Storage="m_parentid")]
public int ParentId { get { return m_parentid; } set { m_parentid = value; } }
```

I can understand B would be different from A and C in the case of a non-trivial getter / setter (Linq would presumably use the getter/setter in case B but not in case A or C, is that correct?)

But I don't understand how there can ever be any difference between A and C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is useful to allow the engine to understand expression trees, for example a predicate:

```
var items = ctx.SomeTable.Where(x => x.ParentId == 21);
```

With "a" I would expect this to fail, as it doesn't really know about the property `ParentId` (only the field `m_parentid` and the database column). Specifying the "Storage" in "c" allows the db-value to be saved directly to the field rather than using the property, avoiding code that shouldn't be necessary during materialisation from the db.

Answer (score 0):

For case A, I agree with Marc Gravell.

In Case B it is just like using a private data member `m_ParentId` is acccessible through the public property ParentID. And the property is mapped with table column parentId.

Case C will produce error at the time of `db.getTable(<Class Name>)`. Because you are using name and storage properties together.